# real time web-camera frames processing

Tags: javascript, html, browser

in case of AudioAPI there are nodes to process the raw data taken from stream

like this:

```
var context = new AudioContext();
var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
var processor = context.createScriptProcessor(1024, 1, 1);

source.connect(processor);
processor.connect(context.destination);`
```

and then on the ScriptProcessor node I can get access to samples by using onaudioprocess event

Now I need to do the same with video stream, to get access to frames to process some of them.
What is the way to do that?